# How to get contents of a file in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get content of all the files in my directory and I am getting an error that says

> ErrorException in Util.php line 114: 
>   preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

. Below is the code that I am using.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $directory = storage_path('app/xmlentries/uploads');
    $files = File::files($directory);
    foreach ($files as $file)        
    {
        $contents = Storage::get($file);
        dd($contents);        
    }
```

How would i get the contents of all my files in this folder?

Comment: Which line of code is throwing that error? Can you post the full error?

Comment: I have edited my question with full error. File that is calling the error is in vendor/league/flysystem/src/Util.php. Surely error is being caused by my code not the Util.php file.

Comment: Did you verify that `$file` inside the loop is always a string and not an array?

Comment: How do i represent your question as code, will i be correct to say that you want me to **dd($file);**  ? 

If that is the case, it still gives me same error as above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$directory = storage_path('app/xmlentries/uploads/');

foreach (glob($directory . "*") as $file) {
    $fileContent = file_get_contents($file);
    dd($fileContent); // change this per your need
}
```

Please note this will display the first file and then stop!

Comment: It doesn't display the contents in the file. Just displays empty quotation marks  - **" "**.

Comment: can you just dd($file) inside the loop and let me know what it shows?

Comment: It outputs the storage_path which **app/xmlentries/uploads**